# Find the area of the region enclosed by $x=2-y^2$ and $x+y=0$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

When I change the equations to equal $x$. I get $\frac{11}{2}$

However, when I change the equations to equal $y$ I don't get the same answer.

Here is my work so far:

Change the equations to equal $y$:

$y=\pm\sqrt{-x+2}$

$y=-x$

Find the points of intersection:

$-x=\sqrt{-x+2}$

$x^2=-x+2$

$x^2+x-2=0$

$(x+2)(x-1)$

$x=-2$ and $x=1 $

$\int_{-2}^{0} (x-\sqrt{-x+2})dx$

Get the antiderivative:

$[\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{2}{3}(-x+2)^\frac{3}{2}]|_{-2}^{0}$

$=\frac{2}{3}2^\frac{3}{2} + 2$

Do the same for the next integral:

$\int_{0}^{1} (-x--\sqrt{-x+2})dx$

$\int_{0}^{1} (-x+\sqrt{-x+2})dx$

Get the antiderivative:

$[-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{2}{3}(-x+2)^\frac{3}{2}]|_{0}^{1}$

$=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{3}2^\frac{3}{2}$

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here because when I add these two answers up from both integrals, I don't get same same answer as $\frac{11}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Finding the area with respect to y is easier.
If you want to calculate it your way, then set up the integrals with respect to x differently.
Referring to the the general graph below:
[image]

$$\int_{-2}^1 \sqrt{2-x}-(-x)dx+\int_1^2 \sqrt{2-x}-(-\sqrt{2-x})dx=
[-\frac{2}{3}(2-x)^\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}x^2]|_{-2}^1+2[-\frac{2}{3}(2-x)^\frac{3}{2}]|_1^2=[(-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{2})-(-\frac{2}{3}\cdot8+\frac{1}{2}\cdot4)]+2[0-(-\frac{2}{3})]=-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{10}{3}+\frac{4}{3}=\frac{27}{6}=\frac{9}{2}.$$
Note: The general rule for the integrand is to subtract from the above function the below function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here: $=\frac{2}{3}2^\frac{3}{2} + 2$

It should be  $\frac{2}{3}2^\frac{3}{2} - (2 + \frac{2}{3}(4)^\frac{3}{2})$

Also the second antiderivative should be $[-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{2}{3}(-x+2)^\frac{3}{2}]|_{0}^{1}$

However, there are bigger problems: since both equations are in terms of $x$, your equation should be using $y$ and $dy$. Also you subtract the two areas. Thus the area is $\int_{-1}^2(2-y^2 - (-y))dy = 4.5$

Comment: Thanks, so since you only pointed out this equation. I'm assuming the other integral is fine?

Comment: @Mark you forget a negative sign

Comment: I'm still not getting the answer I should be getting. I've added $\frac{2}{3}2^\frac{3}{2}-(2+\frac{2}{3}(4)^\frac{3}{2})+\frac{-7}{6}+\frac{2}{3}(2)^\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: this includes negative you corrected me with.

Comment: @Mark I've updated my answer

Comment: @pwr thanks, the question I am working on wants the integral with respect to $y$ and $x$ I thought I got the equations in terms of $y$ correct which is why I was working on in terms of $x$.

Comment: forgive me if I am mistaken but isn't the area in terms of $y$ $5.5$?